# Undefined variable: users in group_member.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to search email from database table **(users)** I want to display email and name in my view **group_member** on the match of email. After database operation in searchmember I verified my code with

`dd($users->email);`

`dd($users->name);`

its work fine its print the email and name but with I pass the data to view it says undefined variable in my view **users**

Here is my Controller file: **StudentController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
// use App\Student;
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function groupmember()
    {
        return view('group_member');
    }
    public function searchmember(Request $request)
    {
        $search=$request->get('searchmember');
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required'
        ]);
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
        if($users != NULL)
        {
            return view("group_member",compact("users"));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/groupmember')->with('Info', 'No such email found');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my View: **group_member.blade.php** located inside views folder

```
<div class="actual-group-member">
            <div>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($users as $user1)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{$user1->name}}</td>
                            <td> {{$user1->email}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

And Here is my Route Web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');

Route::get('/groupmember', 'StudentController@groupmember');
Route::get('/searchmember', 'StudentController@searchmember');
```

Help me sort out this, I am new to laravel,

Comment: Since your `groupmember` function, it also returns the `group_member` view, where you use the `$users` variable, you must return that variable along with the view, as you have done in the other function `searchmember`. But note that in the view, you try to make a foreach about the variable, but when you make the query to DB, you indicate that get only the first record, so the foreach would not make sense. You can change `first()` to `get()` so that the query will returns a collection.

Comment: Thanks i solve this out

Comment: Good for you that you solved it, but tell us how you did it, the accepted answer obviously does not solve the problem posed, but the other one, might be that it does solve it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `->first()` method in your query builder, So It returns a single object of user, **Not** collection,

Change these lines in your **controller**.

```php
// you are getting 1 user. So $user not $users
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
```

```php
// return $user object to view with key 'user'
return view("group_member",["user"=>$user]);
```

In your **group_member View**

```
// We are getting 1 user, So no need loop
<tr>
    <td> {{$user->name}}</td>
    <td> {{$user->email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
```

is correctly pulling a **single object**, `$users`.  Not a collection.

When you get to your blade view, these lines are trying to loop through a *collection* of users:

```
@foreach($users as $user1)
    <tr>
        <td> {{$user1->name}}</td>
        <td> {{$user1->email}}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

To fix, first it would be helpful to name the original object `$user`, since it is singular in your DB pull.

So, in your **controller** inside `searchmember`:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email', $request->email)->first();
// ... return the singlular in compact:  return view("group_member",compact("user"));
```

Then, on your blade page, no need to loop, you have the single user who matched email, so skip the `@foreach` and just use:

```
 <td> {{$user->name}}</td>
 <td> {{$user->email}}</td>
```

In the first method, you still have to pass a variable for `$user` or it will be fail:

```
 public function groupmember()
{
    $user = false;
    return view('group_member', compact('user'));
}
```

Then on the blade page, take account for this;

```
@if($user)
    <td> {{$user->name}}</td>
    <td> {{$user->email}}</td>
@endif
```